# Haskell, traversable getting values from Maybe [list]

Tags: list, haskell, pattern-matching, option-type

Found the need for using `Traversable`. It returned a list like this generates: `fReplList = Just [2,4..100]`.

I know how to return `Maybe` value within a list like: `[Just 1, Just 2, Nothing]`, but I don't know how to pattern-match a Maybe-list like: `Just [2,4,6,8..100]`. I am a beginner (still) and feel bad I am still running in these rudimentary problems, but maybe you can help.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you're asking. Could you share some code and/or give some sample input and output from the function you want to implement?

Comment: Yes, using pseudo-code. With `traversable` I end up with this `Maybe` list:
`Just [1,2,3]`
I would like to have a proper and safe way to get it 'unlifted' and out of context like:
`[1,2,3]`, so getting it away from the Maybe to perform non-fancy functions.

Comment: So the list is irrelevant, and you want a "safe" way to extract the underlying value (if any) from a `Maybe` value? Are you aware of `fromMaybe`: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe ? I'm still a little confused and think I may have missed something, because you keep referring to `Traversable` specifically, yet it seems like your real issue is with `Maybe`.

Comment: `Traversable` is irrelevant; it's just the way you ended up with a value of type `Num a => Maybe [a]`. Your real question is to find a function of type `Num a => Maybe [a] -> [a]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pattern-match on a `Maybe [Int]` just like you pattern-match on any `Maybe a`:

```
foo (Just x) = x
foo Nothing = -- ?
```

The question is: *what do you return in the Nothing case?* (To be clear, the above code snippet doesn't compile because `foo` doesn't return anything in the `Nothing` case.)

Sometimes, you can decide to do something to the `x` inside of `Just`, and then put the result back into a `Just` case:

```
map' f (Just x) = Just (f x)
map' _ Nothing = Nothing
```

That's exactly what `fmap` does already for `Maybe a`, which is why I named the example function `map'`. With `fmap`, you can map a `Maybe [Int]` like this:

```
Prelude> fmap show (Just [2,4,6,8,100])
Just "[2,4,6,8,100]"
```

Notice that this turns the entire list into a `String`, because `fmap` applies to `Maybe`, not to `[]`.

While, in general, it's hard to say what to return in the case of `Nothing`, for lists (and other monoids) a natural 'default value' exists. So, specifically for `Maybe [a]`, you could write something like this:

```
maybeListToList :: Maybe [a] -> [a]
maybeListToList (Just xs) = xs
maybeListToList Nothing = []
```

Using it could look like this:

```
*Q54645038> maybeListToList (Just [2,4,6,8,100])
[2,4,6,8,100]
*Q54645038> maybeListToList Nothing
[]
```

It's not really necessary, though, because you could instead combine existing functions from `Data.Maybe` and the standard `Prelude` to get the same functionality:

```
Prelude Data.Maybe> maybeToList (Just [2,4,6,8,100])
[[2,4,6,8,100]]
Prelude Data.Maybe> concat (maybeToList (Just [2,4,6,8,100]))
[2,4,6,8,100]
Prelude Data.Maybe> concat (maybeToList Nothing)
[]
```

Notice how `maybeToList` turns any `Maybe a` into a list. When `a` is already a list, you get a nested list that you can then flatten with `concat`.

Comment: Thanks @Mark Seemann. Answer solved the problem... Sorry could not see it myself.